# Class constructors not visible in class

Tags: java, class

I'm trying to simplify some java code I wrote as a first project by dividing it up into classes. I am very new to this so I created this below but at the marked point I keep on getting the error:

```
Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class TxtExtr_AnatomyRegex {
private String x;
private Map<String,String> map= new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
private String [] seAnatomy=null;
private ArrayList<String> Anatomy_arr = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<List<String>> Anatomy_table2d = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
String el[]=null;

    public TxtExtr_AnatomyRegex(String x,Map<String,String> map) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        x=this.x;
        map=this.map;
    }
    Pattern Anatomy_pattern = Pattern.compile("Anatomy\\*(.*?Hiatal hernia[^\n]*)",Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher matcherAnatomy_pattern = Anatomy_pattern.matcher(x); /////////////////////////////////ERROR IS HERE

    while (matcherAnatomy_pattern.find()) {
        seAnatomy=matcherAnatomy_pattern.group(1).split("\\n|\\r");
    }

    for (int ise=0;ise<seAnatomy.length;ise++){ 
        Anatomy_arr.add(seAnatomy[ise]);
    }
    for (String ss:Anatomy_arr){
    ArrayList<String> tbb = new ArrayList<String>();
    el=ss.split("\\t");
        for (String e:el){
            if(!e.isEmpty()){
              tbb.add(e.trim());
             }
        }
             if(!tbb.isEmpty()){
             Anatomy_table2d.add(tbb);
             for (int ff=0;ff<Anatomy_table2d.size();ff++){
                    //Symptom
                 map.put("SumAnatomy"+Anatomy_table2d.get(ff).get(0),Anatomy_table2d.get(ff).get(1));
                      }
             }
     }
    System.out.println(Anatomy_table2d);

}
}
```

I appreciate I'll get a lot of 'read about classes you newbie' type comments....(and I have but thanks)....but I think the problem is that I need to put Matcher `matcherAnatomy_pattern = Anatomy_pattern.matcher(x);` up in the declared variables. This I did only to get another error that it is not visible. What fundamental concept am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything what you wrote after your constructor has to be encaspulated in the constructor or in separate methods. You can use your anatomy_pattern and so on as attributes of your class.

```
public class TxtExtr_AnatomyRegex {
     private String x;
     private Map<String,String> map= new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
     private String [] seAnatomy=null;
     private ArrayList<String> Anatomy_arr = new ArrayList<String>();
     private ArrayList<List<String>> Anatomy_table2d = new      ArrayList<List<String>>();
     String el[]=null;
     Pattern Anatomy_pattern = null;
     Matcher atcherAnatomy_pattern = null;

     public TxtExtr_AnatomyRegex(String x,Map<String,String> map) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        x=this.x;
        map=this.map;

        Anatomy_pattern = Pattern.compile("Anatomy\\*(.*?Hiatal hernia[^\n]*)",Pattern.DOTALL);
        matcherAnatomy_pattern = Anatomy_pattern.matcher(x); /////////////////////////////////ERROR IS HERE

      //...put here your for and while stuff

      }//end of the constructur


      //... some methods ... you maybe also can do something of the loops in methods

  } //end of the class
```

Answer (score 1):

Reasonably formatted code, in the [online java compiler IDE](https://kasadara.com/p/c684d9e2-e672-4ca6-84d7-d15e0415aa45).

The issue is, the control structure like while, for etc can be present only within a method. In this case, you have added it directly within the class block.

Wrap the lines that follows the constructor inside a method, then it will compile.

As a side note, I would advice you to follow java coding style guides.

```
public class TxtExtr_AnatomyRegex {
  private String x;
  private Map<String,String> map= new LinkedHashMap<String,String>();
  private String [] seAnatomy=null;
  private ArrayList<String> Anatomy_arr = new ArrayList<String>();
  private ArrayList<List<String>> Anatomy_table2d = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
  String el[]=null;

  public TxtExtr_AnatomyRegex(String x, Map<String,String> map) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    x=this.x;
    map=this.map;
  }

  public void doSomething() {
    Pattern Anatomy_pattern = Pattern.compile("Anatomy\\*(.*?Hiatal hernia[^\n]*)",Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher matcherAnatomy_pattern = Anatomy_pattern.matcher(x);
    // and other code also here
  }
}
```